# Switching from ASP.NET code-behind to Play MVC and have lots of questions

Tags: model-view-controller, playframework

1. How do I dynamically render HTML in Play? For example I have an enum or DB table with a list of platforms (pc/xbox/ps3). I want to render in my HTML form a checkbox list with each of those. For now I've just hard coded the HTML form with elements, but long term it needs to be dynamic and the lists (checkbox/radio/dropdown) need to be bound to the system so they receive new items as new items are added to the database.
2. On postback how do i access those form fields in the controller handling the postback? I've found that in the controller action's function parameter list I can specify the name of the form field, and that works, but this is unrealistic if i'm going to have forms that have 100 fields, then I do'nt want to have to declare 100 params in my controller action function.

Comment: And yes I've done all the tutorials on play framework .org and read their docs, but I'm still having issues translating my ASP.NET code-behind habits to MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can call method `values()` on enums to obtain array of enum values. And then map it to List. For example you can use `Lists.newArrayList(array)` from google-collections.
2. form parameters you can find in `request.params` hashmap. Request is a field inherited from play.mvc.Controller.

Also have a look at this http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/cheatsheet/controllers. (Usefull stuff but not easy to find)

UPD

`List theList =....;`
`render(theList);`

and in the template (example for select):

```
<select id="viewSelect" size="1" >
  #{list items:theList, as:'listItem'}
   <option id="${listItem.getId()}">${listItem.getName()}</option>
  #{/list}
</select>
```

Comment: And then how do I get that list to show up as an HTML checkbox list on my page?

Comment: I'll look into request.params, that sounds perfect for what I need.

Comment: oh wow, I totally am using Play wrong. Thanks for the same code, that's way more elegant than what I as going to do. Thank you!

Comment: So this is great for rendering it , but then is there a fancy way to hydrate the list on postback or is it all a process of manually inspecting the request.params hashmap? And how do I tell is "checked == true"  ? If there isn't a fancy way I'm happy to just look for the checkbox names in the form post and null values represent unchecked boxes. But in .NET it's nice because I get state back for all the checkboxes checked or not, and there is a ".checked" property. Anything like that built into play?

Comment: Oddly enough, I found that if I have an html element like a set of checkboxes where they all have the same name,(name="chkFavoriteNumbers"), that when using request.params.get("chkFavoriteNumbers"), it only returns the first checked checkbox even if multiple were checked. However if I use request.params.all(), which returns a proper hashmap, the value of each entryset is a String[] and then I get all checked items returned. So I'm using  String[] myCheckedBoxes = request.params.all().get("chkFavoriteNumbers");

Comment: of course I'm sure there's a more elegant way in play to do this using models or something but until I learn play I'm just writing manual HTML and manually parsing request.params.

Comment: haven't implemented the case for myself but yes you can use models or better say pojos. See the "POJO object binding" subsection http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/controllers#binding